# Cannot join CIFS server to a active directory domain

Tags: networking, cisco, storage, storage-area-network, emc-vnx

We have a VNX5700 in our environment , it had two datamovers(one as primary and the other secondary). Recently we added a third datamover to the array and configured it as an active DM , so we will have two active and one standby DM.

Our issue is that when we try creating CIFS server , its not joining to  the domain it throws the error " the operation failed due to a communication problem with DataMover...control station was unable to send request or receive response from Datamover"

We have tried:

1. adding DNS records to Datamover
2. We found that the time to be off on the new DM by more than 5 min,this is fixed now.
3. We have compared with the configuration and vlan of the network port with the network port of the other DM that works fine-> the configuration is found to be the same, except that both resides on different port channels
4. we tried rebooting the DM .
5. getreason command gives the output  for all DM as 'contacted'
6. We are able to ping the default gateway from the DM that works fine, but we cannot ping the same ip from the new DM

Please advice what should be the next step taken to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's an internal network that the data movers and control station use to talk to each other. If they're complaining about communication problems, I'd start there. Can you ping all the data movers from the control station?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you have a basic IP communications problem re: #6. Get your IP fundamentals right first.